# Adding field in one shapefile which lists where each attribute of that file overlaps with another shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, overlapping-features

I have two shapefiles, one has points where people divert water from rivers, the other has polygons of land ownership. I would like to add a field in the attribute table of the points shapefile which lists which land ownership polygons each point overlaps with.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @whyzar I tried downloading the "FInd overlapping features" add in (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=968e6a55a11640d2b9cfa211104d3811), but I received an error when trying to run it and have not had success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to your point features "Ownership".

Execute 'spatial join' from the toolbox.

Target features are the points, join features are the polygons.

In the field map, right click on "Ownership" field and select 'add input field'.  Select the ownership field from your polygon features.

You will get an output feature class of the points with the polygon ownership attribute included.

Comment: No worries.  Add-ons (like your 'Find Overlapping Features' tool) can be very useful but you should always look to the standard toolset first.  There is a search bar in ArcGIS where you can search through the tools with keywords.